# What is the meaning of "one-half meter"?

Tags: measuring-units

I have found this phrase that as a non-native English speaker perplexes me:

> ...returning images with a resolution of up to one-half meter per pixel.

The possible meanings of "one-half" to me are:

- Every pixel represents half a meter
- Every pixel represents one and a half (1.5) meters
- Every pixel may represent any possible distance between the minimum of half a meter and the maximum of one meter
- Something entirely different

Can you please explain?

N.B. Is it

*one and a half meter*

OR

*one and a half meter**s*** ?

Comment: Without more context it's hard to say, but your first interpretation is probably correct.  The statement would make sense for satellite photos, eg.  There is no way that "one-half meter" would logically be said when the intent is "1.5 meters".

Comment: The source is the Ars-Technica article: Inside NASA’s daring $8 billion plan to finally find extraterrestrial life. https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/03/inside-nasas-daring-8-billion-plan-to-finally-find-extraterrestrial-life/ Look at the section "A prudent, but costly, pathway". Not much more context however, IMO.

Comment: That's no help.

Comment: @TrevorD:  I've asked a follow-on question about the meaning of "up to" in this context.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377423/is-this-usage-of-up-to-ambiguous

Comment: Three-quarters and seven-tenths etc are very common, but for some reason one-half isn't, we would just say half.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me (a British English native) the expression is unambiguous in meaning:

> 0.5 metre per pixel  [UK *metre* = US *meter*]
>      *i.e.* one-half of a metre per pixel

In answer to your N.B., the plural form would be:

> one and a half metre**s** (or meter**s**)
>      1.5 metre**s** (or meter**s**)

Addendum:
Additionally, also note that the resolution is "*up to* one-half meter per pixel", so the resolution may be less than 0.5m per pixel, but no lower resolution limit is specified.

Comment: I agree, but it should be pointed out that the hyphenation in the example is incorrect or mistranscribed. If it is hyphenated at all it should be "one half-metre" — the half is associated with the metre, not the one. This may have been the cause of (or contributed to) the poster's difficulty.

Comment: @David I wouldn't make that assumption. I don't know why it was hyphenated - but I don't consider it as necessarily wrong. I read it as 'one half' of a metre, as distinct from (for example) 'three-quarters' of a metre, or 'one-quarter' of a metre. Granted, it's slightly unusual phraseology, but not necessarily wrong.

Comment: As you can see at the question's comments, the texted was an exact copy-paste from an Ars-Technical article.